# Custom Directive - $watch not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Please refer to this plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/pB8Pa5rz3XnIhsqP8rQL?p=preview

```
var str = $scope.myOptions.split(' ');
  var itemStr = str[0];
  var collectionName = str[2];

  $scope.$watch(collectionName,function(collection){
    console.log(collection);
    for(var i=0;i<collection.length;i++){
      $scope.item.push(collection[i]);
    }
  });
```

I see that the collectionName is populated correctly and the watch function is called. But why doesn't it parse the collection? It gets undefined instead of the collection array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use the link function. I was trying to read the array using:

```
scope: {myOptions: '@'}
```

@ only gets string and the directive has no way to resolve that to the model.

Using the link function, you can watch the model and perform operations on it

Answer (score 0):

Your directive has an isolate scope, so it doesn't have access to the `states` variable on the controller.  You'll have to pass that into the directive so that it can see it.

Check this plunk:

http://plnkr.co/edit/smLmR1l09sFoqbx3OSu0?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am trying to recreate ng-options in the select tag. I want to create a multi select box which has check boxes in them. Since select doesnt have the option to add checkboxes, I have no option but to create a custom directive. I would have directly pulled in the states array like you pointed out but the point is that I want the user to have similar functionality as ngOptions. Is there no way to get around this?

Comment: I think you can still have that with the way this is structured.  You would just pass your options to the custom directive.  Just like I'm passing in the states array here.

Comment: but then it defeats the whole purpose because the usage is not similar to the select tag. The way we use select tag is this: <select ng-options="item as item.label for item in items" ng-model="selected"></select>. As you see above the items array is not being passed separately.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking.  Maybe post another question clarifying what you mean?